# iad's asset : SVG. How to embed image?

Tags: iphone, svg, iad

I'm now trying to import a svg in my iAds where the code

```
<image x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="logo.jpg"/>
```

When I open the svg with a browser, I'm able to see the `logo.jpg`, but when I import the svg into iAd as asset I'm not able to view the `logo.jpg`.

It always shows a "?" for the image... obviously couldn't find my `logo.jpg`, even though my svg file and `logo.jpg` are located in the same folder "assets".

Can anyone help me, please :(

Answer (score 2):

Add below tag into your main SVG tag before linking image into your SVG file

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can get your image into an SVG by importing into an SVG editor like Inkscape. Your image will be in 64 bit format. The SVG does not hold a path reference to it, which is why you get the question mark.